# findOneAndUpdate not updating the document and returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and mongoose.

Please help me out! I'm stuck in this problem that I describe below.

This is my code.
addressSchema and another schema for saving user id and the address

when i try to update the document im not getting any response from the below code.
but when i try 'find()' im getting the response.

```
 const addressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 40
    },
    mobileNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true 
    },
    pincode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    landmark: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    alternatePhoneNo: {
        type: String
    },
    addressType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: [ 'home', 'work' ]
    }
})
        Schema for storing the address array and user ID  

const userAddressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    address: [addressSchema]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

```
    I tried updating many ways but still cant update
```

//Code to update the document

```
const editAddress = (req, res) => {
    const { address } = req.body

    if(address) {
        UserAddress.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
        .exec((error, _userAddress) => {
            if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error })

            if(_userAddress) {
                UserAddress.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": _userAddress._id,"address._id": address._id }, {
                    "$set": {
                        "address.$": {
                            "name": address.name,
                            "mobileNo": address.mobileNo,
                            "pincode": address.pincode,
                            "landmark": address.landmark,
                            "address": address.address,
                            "area": address.area,
                            "state": address.state,
                            "alternatePhoneNo": address.alternatePhoneNo,
                            "addressType": address.addressType
                        }
                    }
                })
                .exec((error, data) => {
                    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error })
                    if(data) return res.status(201).json({ data })
                    console.log(error)
                    console.log(data)
                })
            }  
        })  
    }
}
```

Guys please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: from where are you getting this property **_userAddress._id **?

Comment: @MontyTomar changed my code please check that

Comment: Tried adding new: true and returnOriginal: false and also upsert

Comment: UserAddress.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": _userAddress._id,"address._id": address.id }, try removing the underscore before the value of ** address._id  ** property.

Comment: i tried that still no response

Comment: Can you copy paste the result of console.log(address) by consoling right after `const { address } = req.body
` this line?

Comment: @MontyTomar Here is the logged address {
  _id: '60b79a270fe87b061ce4d981',
  name: 'Thrijesh',
  mobileNo: '9482732713',
  pincode: '321321',
  landmark: 'Madikeri',
  address: 'India',
  area: 'Madikeri',
  state: 'Karnataka',
  alternatePhoneNo: '123123123',
  addressType: 'work'
}

Answer (score 0):

Try `awaiting` the `.findOneAndUpdate()` function:

```js
const editAddress = async (req, res) => {
    const { address } = req.body

    if(address) {
        await UserAddress.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
        .exec((error, _userAddress) => {
            if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error })

            if(_userAddress) {
                await UserAddress.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": _userAddress._id,"address._id": address._id }, {
                    "$set": {
                        "address.$": {
                            "name": address.name,
                            "mobileNo": address.mobileNo,
                            "pincode": address.pincode,
                            "landmark": address.landmark,
                            "address": address.address,
                            "area": address.area,
                            "state": address.state,
                            "alternatePhoneNo": address.alternatePhoneNo,
                            "addressType": address.addressType
                        }
                    }
                })
                .exec((error, data) => {
                    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error })
                    if(data) return res.status(201).json({ data })
                    console.log(error)
                    console.log(data)
                })
            }  
        })  
    }
}
```

`Awaiting` this fixed my error too.

Comment: I tried awaiting still im not getting any response from that

Comment: Try removing the `brackets` for `_id` and `adress._id` in your `.findOneAndUpdate()` function

Comment: i did try removing that. Its showing me error in the code

Comment: If i remove the Brackets i'm getting error in the code

Comment: Or try chaning your first object in `.findOneAndUpdate()` to `{ _id: _userAddress._id, address: { _id: address._id }`

Comment: Nope not working still not getting any response not an error or data